# Python Nested Try/Except/Else for Control Flow

Tags: python, nested, try-except, idempotent

What I'd like to achieve in the most elegant Python way:
Try to find an object in the database on a certain filter. Only if there is no result, then try to find the object using another filter. If that returns no result, then the object does not exist, so insert a new instance.

What I'm thinking:

```
try:
    obj = session.query(model).filter_by(field_a).one()
except NoObjFound:
    try:
        obj = session.query(model).filter_by(field_b).one()
    except NoObjFound:
        insert_into_db(brand_new_obj)
else:
    update_the_obj(obj)
```

I'm not sure if this block is correct or the best way to handle what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: A downside of what you currently have is that the `else` only applies to the first `try`; the inner `try` will never reach that line.

Comment: You should indent once again the else clause to make it to update just when there is no result in both filters. But I hope this is *pythonic* as I use it frequently...

Comment: Indenting the `else` clause to belong to the inner `try/except` block will hide it from the outer `try/except` block. This isn't what the author wants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest something like:

```
for filter in (field_a, field_b):
    try:
        obj = session.query(model).filter_by(filter).one()
    except NoObjFound:
        pass # or 'continue'
    else:
        update_the_obj(obj)
        break
else:
    insert_into_db(brand_new_obj)
```

This will ensure that the correct things happen in the correct order, is more readable than nested `try` blocks and can easily be extended to add more `filter`s.

Comment: Beat me to it ... I think `continue` makes more sense than `pass` as per my answer; if you agree and edit your answer, I'll delete mine as a dupe (otherwise, might as well have both alternatives on the table).

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus `continue` and `pass` are exactly equivalent here, as there is no additional content within the `for` block. `continue` is useful where you want to skip the things that happen in the rest of the block, but that doesn't apply here.

Comment: In terms of the effect on flow control, yes it's identical, but since the intent is to "continue looking for an object", `continue` feels more expressive to me. Personal taste, I guess. Anyway, deleted mine and upvoted yours :-)

Comment: Appreciate the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect. Assuming you want to `update_the_obj(obj)` after finding the object independent of which filter found it, the `else` clause at the end is hidden to the inner filter.

You can try:

```
obj = None
try:
    obj = session.query(model).filter_by(field_a).one()
except NoObjFound:
    try:
        obj = session.query(model).filter_by(field_b).one()
    except NoObjFound:
        insert_into_db(brand_new_obj)

if obj is not None:
    update_the_obj(obj)
```

Comment: If `obj` isn't assigned inside the `try`, you will get a `NameError` on `if obj:`.

Comment: You should check for singletons like `None` with identity (`if obj is not None`) - `False` or `0` or an empty container may be valid values, but would fail a simple `if obj` condition